# Why does my hash show a value, but when I access it with [] it comes back nil?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this block of code, to try and debug what's coming back to my server:

```
task = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

puts task.inspect
puts 'description hash: ' 
puts task[:description]
```

When this block of code runs, I get:

```
{"completed" => false, "task_type" => 0, "description"=> "second task"}
description hash: 
nil
```

Is there a different way to access this hash? Because from what I see the inspection shows a description value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Problem

In the example you gave, you are defining a hash key of "description" but looking up the :description key instead, which doesn't exist. The reason is that the first is a String, and the second is a Symbol.

```
"description".class
=> String

:description.class
=> Symbol
```

#### The Solution

Either look up your key with a string, or call #to_s on your subscript if you know your keys are always a String, but your subscript may not be.

```
task['description']
=> "second task"

task[:description.to_s]
=> "second task"
```

Comment: Worth noting that Rails uses [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) to allow accessing via symbols or string of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

`:description` isn't the same as `'description'`. This should work:

```
puts task['description']
```